# Palatalization in English words like street, storm, etc

Tags: phonetics, palatalization

More and more people on television are pronouncing *street* as "shtreet" and *storm* as "shtorm", replacing the initial /s/ with /ʃ/.  Where and when did this start in mainstream America?

Comment: It's not a new phenomenon. Also, here are links to this question (well-answered) on english.stackexchange:
[Original](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10309/pronunciation-of-voiceless-alveolar-fricative-s-as-ʃ-sh-in-slang)
, [Duplicate](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84836/why-is-str-sometimes-pronounced-as-shtr)

Comment: I think the question, by itself, is on-topic. However, I'm voting to close because it has already received good quality answers on EL&U.

Comment: Is this called palatalization? I thought palatalization is pronouncing soft "s" rather than changing "s" to "sh"

Comment: @Anixx Yes, *palatalization* is commonly used to describe this phenomenon.  See e.g. Michael Shapiro's [*A Case of Distant Assimilation:* /str/ > /ʃtr/](http://www.languagelore.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/assimilation-at-a-distance.pdf), American Speech, 70 (1995), 101-107.

Comment: @snailboat then what is the term for soft consonants? I thought is is called palatalization in English.